# How will i change agent name for android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an apps which will load url,and if i load http://www.detectmybrowser.com then it will show my apps name.

when i use below user agent string then it show "You're using Mozill version an Unknown version on Linux"

but i want look like "You're using AppName version 1.0 on android"

Is there any way to solving..

simple code:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes-  change the user agent to a custom name.  You can't have it claim to be Mozilla and then have that site think you're something else.

Comment: Change Mozilla top your app name, and Linux to Android

Comment: i have used like below, unfortunately http://www.detectmybrowser.com are shown "you are using Mozilla unknown version  "  and http://www.whatismybrowser.com shown "your browser is Android Browser".... webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AppName/5.0 (android; U; Android 5.0; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");